# Cómo proteger una aplicación iOS de dumps de clases como el class-dump?

Tags: ios

Estoy creando una aplicación en iOS y logro hacer un dump de métodos con classdumpios. He comparado mi app con algunas bancarias, y éstas no arrojan resultados con los métodos dump.

Saben cuál puede ser el método de protección aplicado por estas aplicaciones? Gracias!.

Comment: No es lo mismo una App que ejecutas desde el Xcode a una que pase por un proceso de encriptación y revisión que hace Apple en el AppStore. Por eso no puedes ver resultados de otras apps.

Comment: Es una buena pregunta pero está basada en opiniones por lo que generaría su cierre.